# how to deal with Intermediate MySQL tables on Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysqli, scaffolding

I have one table of chefs, one table of restaurants and an intermediate table that relates the restaurants in which a chef has worked

```
|–––––––––––––––––|  |–––––––––––––––––|  |–––––––––––––––––|
| chef            |  | restaurant      |  | chef_restaurant |
|-----------------|  |-----------------|  |-----------------|
| chef_id         |  | restaurant_id   |  | restaurant_id   |
| name            |  | name            |  | chef_id         |
|_________________|  |_________________|  |_________________|
```

1. If I use scaffolding in rails should I generate the scafold for the 3 tables? Does the fact of having intermediate tables in your SQL model is an impair for using scaffolding?
2. What's your approach to query those intermediate tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to scaffold chef and restaurant. And for relationship table you don't need models and controls, so just a migration to create relationship table is enough. Two things need to keep in mind were, including habt relationship in chef and restaurant models. And following the naming convention for your relationship table, it must have both table names in plural, in ascending orders. Your relationship table name must be chefs_restaurants

Rails migration allows to create it easily like below

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTable chefs restaurants
```

And in your chef model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :restuarants
```

in your restaurant model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :chefs
```

Comment: Really good the info you gave me. I understood the second convention about alphabetical order. But what did you meant with 

"Two things need to keep in mind were, including habt relationship in chef and restaurant models"

That I should include what?

Comment: sorry if i'm not clear. that is just defining the relationship in both the model classes, pls check the answer now I have updated

Comment: That's great. But my main concern is: Do I need to create a controller and a model for this intermediate tables after running the migration and creating the table?

Comment: as i suggested just the migration to create the table. ActiveRecord will do everything if you follow the above two steps.

Comment: I understood, but may I ask if I insert something in the chef table and in the restaurant table will ActiveRecord update this intermediate table with a row?.....Thank you so much!!

Comment: Yes once it's saved in database.

Comment: You are the man my friend!! I guess I'll have to keep reading about ActiveRecord!!